# How to install easy_install in Python 2.7.1 on Windows 7

Tags: python, easy-install

I have installed Python 2.7.1 on Windows 7, but I am unable to install easy_install.
Please help me.

Comment: [Look Here](http://www.varunpant.com/posts/how-to-setup-easy_install-on-windows) this link provides a step by step tutorial

Answer (score 45):

I usually just run [ez_setup.py](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py). IIRC, that works fine, at least with UAC off.

It also creates an easy_install executable in your Python\scripts subdirectory, which should be in your PATH.

UPDATE: I highly recommend not to bother with easy_install anymore! Jump right to pip, it's better in every regard!
Installation is just as simple: from the [installation instructions](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html#install-pip) page, you can download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and run it. Works just like the ez_setup.py mentioned above.

Comment: `pip` also has its fair share of issues with installing packages where `easy_install` comes for the rescue eg: [upgrading pip with pip on windows fails](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5820#issuecomment-460649655), [pip install hashlib fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36362235/8608146)

Answer (score 20):

for 32-bit Python, the installer is [here](http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/).  after you run the installer, you will have `easy_install.exe` in your `\Python27\Scripts` directory

if you are looking for 64-bit installers, this is an excellent resource:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

the author has installers for both Setuptools and Distribute.  Either one will give you `easy_install.exe`

Answer (score 7):

Look for the [official 2.7 setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=57e1e64f6b7c7f1d2eddfc9746bbaf20) installer (which contains easy_install). You only need to install from sources for windows 64 bits.

Answer (score 3):

That tool is part of the setuptools (now called Distribute) package. Install Distribute. Of course you'll have to fetch that one manually.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#installation-instructions

Comment: distribute is a fork of setuptools, not the new name of setuptools.

Comment: This page says that you must install from source which is not correct. There is a windows installer

Answer (score 3):

I recently used `ez_setup.py` as well and I did a tutorial on how to install it. The tutorial has snapshots and simple to follow. You can find it below:

[Installing easy_install Using ez_setup.py](http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-install-easy_install/)

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to install setuptools on Windows is to download ez_setup.py and run it. The script will download the appropriate .egg file and install it for you.

For best results, uninstall previous versions FIRST (see Uninstalling).

Once installation is complete, you will find an easy_install.exe program in your Python Scripts subdirectory. For simple invocation and best results, add this directory to your PATH environment variable, if it is not already present.

more details : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question but it does offer one solution to your problem.  Python 2.7.9 includes PIP and SetupTools, if you update to this version you will have one solution to your problem.