# 'easy_install' is not recognized as an in internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, windows-7, python-2.7, easy-install

I have just downloaded and installed the latest version of Python on my Windows 7 machine.

```
Python 2.7.3
```

Now I want to install a [Twitter library](http://tweepy.github.com/) I found online:

However when I try to run `easy_install tweepy`, I get this error message:

> 'easy_install' is not recognized as an in internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.

Python has already been placed into my path, as I can invoke the Python program into the command line.

---

Here is a screenshot of my folder where Python is installed.

[image]

And inside the Tools folder:

[image]

And inside the scripts folder:

[image]

Comment: Just ran `ez_setup.py` - "Downloading" it says, will post back with results.

Comment: I don't know where this guys comment went, but running this scripts fixed my issue and handled the installation for me. Solved!

Answer (score 11):

You need to:

1. Install easy_install: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools
2. Add `C:\Python27\Scripts` to your `PATH`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with Python 3.4. Fixed it with the steps below:

> cd C:\Python34\Scripts 
>   .\easy_install pip

(or what you need to install)
with the .\ you sort of grant admin permissions to the command

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should [set the 'PATH'](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx) variable in order to execute it

Answer (score 1):

Looks like easy-install is not itself installed on your system.

See this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930216/how-to-install-easy-install-in-python-2-7-1-on-windows-7) for instructions on installing.

Answer (score 0):

> > **Basics official python packages need to be installed**

*You can install packages via the command line by entering:*

```
python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
```

Answer (score 0):

0.Install easy_install

1.search for "edit the system environment variables" in search.

2.click environment variables.

3.under "system variables" click "path" and click edit.

4.click "new".

5.go back and copy the path where python package(easy_install) is installed and paste it there.

6.click ok everything.

7.check now it works...