# 'frozenset' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, hashlib, frozenset

When I attempt to import `hashlib` in any context, it throws this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/hashlib.py", line 115, in <module>
    """
TypeError: 'frozenset' object is not callable
```

Any idea how I can resolve this?  I'm generating this error simply by opening up Terminal, running `python` and then typing `import hashlib`.

Comment: Try from a different working directory.

Comment: I kind of fixed it, in that I removed a bunch of hashlib.py files.  However, now it's not installed and trying to install it with pip or easy_install gives the same frozenset error.

Comment: `hashlib` should be in the standard library. No need to install anything.

Comment: It looks like you have a corrupted custom installation of Python. OS X 10.11 has a built-in Python 2.7 in `/usr/bin/python`, and `hashlib` in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py`.

Comment: I tried importing it on a brand new Mac, and got this error.  What do you recommend doing?

Comment: I have the same erro when installing "hmac" through pip.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday, Hashlib wasn't installed and trying to install it using pip would give that error. I fixed it by installing it using easy_install instead.

Also I had to install Scipy and [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) on Windows, they were required for Hashlib

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem installing hashlib on OSX (El Capitan), after a failed pip install of hashlib and re-attemp using easy_install. After the event, I had errors just calling pip, let alone loading hashlib.

Root cause was pip adding a bad egg directory path to my sys.path and PYTHONHOME:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/hashlib-20081119-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

To fix, you can delete the file referenced directly, in my case:

```
rm /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/hashlib-20081119-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg
```

I tried deleting just the directory reference, but after exploring [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271494/what-sets-up-sys-path-with-python-and-when) to identify the site.py and site_packages.py file belonging to my Current python version, which defines your paths, then looked at where site_packages.py was loading its paths from, it appears that the specific reference is added directly by pip? so the only workaround I could think of was to potentially hard code a line at the end of site.py to remove the reference, which I've seen on other threads.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I found is this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40259767/3689574

It allows to install hashlib with pip with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same message on Fedora 29.

I ended up installing with `easy_install hashlib`, however, I had to do the following steps first:

```
dnf install python2-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS I fixed it by installing it `easy_install hashlib` instead `pip install hashlib`