# frozenset is not callable when installing odoo10

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

Installing fresh version of odoo 10 and try to run odoo.py

It give me that importing hashlib has error

```
the error is 'frozenset' is not callable
```

Comment: First you need search similar questions, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083381/frozenset-object-is-not-callable

Comment: i have done,but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I have to remove hashlib file as shown:

[image]

Comment: It would be preferable if you could provide that information in the answer itself as text instead of posting a link to a picture of text.